# Which characters does TurboGears replace in the URL?

Tags: python, turbogears2, turbogears

I have a simple TurboGears 2 script, named app.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from tg import expose, TGController, AppConfig

class RootController(TGController):
    @expose()
    def all__things(self):
        return "Hello world!"

config = AppConfig(minimal=True, root_controller=RootController())

print("Serving on port 5000...")
httpd = make_server('', 5000, config.make_wsgi_app())
httpd.serve_forever()
```

When I run app.py and visit http://localhost:5000/all__things, I see "Hello world!" as expected. But these URLs also work:

```
http://localhost:5000/all--things
http://localhost:5000/all@@things
http://localhost:5000/all$$things
http://localhost:5000/all++things
http://localhost:5000/all..things
http://localhost:5000/all,,things
```

As well as combinations:

```
http://localhost:5000/all-_things
http://localhost:5000/all_-things
http://localhost:5000/all-@things
http://localhost:5000/all@-things
http://localhost:5000/all$@things
http://localhost:5000/all@$things
```

Et cetera...

What is the complete list of characters that can be substituted for an underscore in TurboGears URLs?

Also, can this feature be restricted to only substitute certain characters? Ideally, I want URLs with dashes (http://localhost:5000/all--things) to work, and URLs with underscores (http://localhost:5000/all__things) or any other strange characters to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's managed by the `path_translator` which can be configured through the `dispatch_path_translator` option in `app_cfg.py`. It can be disabled by passing `None` or providing a custom function.

Any function provided will receive the part of the path currently being processed and must return it normalised.

The default path translator is based on `string.punctuation` (see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Lib/string.py#L31 )

In case you have custom routing needs I suggest you consider https://github.com/TurboGears/tgext.routes which might help you in more complex cases through the `@route` decorator.

Comment: Setting `config.dispatch_path_translator = False` crashes the program, but `config.dispatch_path_translator = None` works. In the end I decided on:

`config.dispatch_path_translator = lambda path_piece: path_piece.replace('-', '_') if not '_' in path_piece else ''`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, it's True/None/function 
I wrote False by reflex as the opposite of True :D

Updated answer